# Sync a Dropbox Folder with iTunes

Tags: windows-xp, itunes, dropbox

Okay here's my scenario.

Dropbox is great for sharing things.  iTunes is great for managing music.  I have a private shared Dropbox folder that I use to share music among my friends.  I use iTunes to manage and listen to my music.  I want Dropbox and iTunes to work seamlessly together to deliver the shared music to my library in a way that is completely hands off for me.

There are several pieces of technology that make this close to happening.

iTunes [just added a feature](http://lifehacker.com/5356619/itunes-finally-adds-watched-folder-to-automatically-add-new-music) to let you drop music into a folder and have it auto imported to your library.

Meanwhile you can [symlink dropbox folders](http://lifehacker.com/5154698/sync-files-and-folders-outside-your-my-dropbox-folder) from within that folder to have it point at your Dropbox.  BUT the problem is iTunes automatically moves those files as soon as you touch them, thus removing them from the Dropbox, and preventing them from being shared.

What I think I need is a solution that somehow either:

1. (ideally) points itunes at a folder within dropbox and automatically adds those files to my library.  I'm aware of [this solution](http://lifehacker.com/software/itunes/hack-attack-automatically-sync-itunes-to-any-folders-175161.php), but am looking for something a bit less effort-intensive.
2. (less ideally) automatically copies new files from my dropbox into the magic itunes folder which then will duplicate them in my library.

Anyone have any thoughts?  I should mention I'm doing this on Windows XP, but would ideally be looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to symlink in Windows XP, care to explain ?

Comment: Did you follow the link?  There is a program you can use called junction.

Comment: technically NT junctions aren't symlinks, but for this purpose they may be close enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could uninstall Dropbox, and then reinstall it with a custom directory within the Itunes Auto-Sync Folder. Or if the choice for a custom directory isn't available, you could try just copy/pasting the Dropbox Directory into the Auto-share folder